# number of favorite and number of retweet from user to user in Twitter

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

I need to do the following 
For each follower to specific  user in Twitter , I need number of favorite  and number of retweet this user do
For example : for user A, suppose userB is userA's follower, I need number  of favorite and number of retweet userB do for userA's Tweets

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the numbers of favorites you could check every favorite of user B and check if is from user A. I suppose that you already have the followers, so

```
for (User B : followers){
ResponseList<Status> favorites = t.getFavorites(B.getId()); // t is your Twitter Instance
for(Status f : favorites)
if(A.getId() == B.getUser().getId()) countF++;
}
```

For the number of retweets, you could do the same. I suppose that you already have the tweets by a follower (you could get up to 3200 with the API)

```
for(Status sB : StatusesB)
if (sB.isRetweet()){ 
if(A.getId() == sB.getRetweetedStatus().getUser().getId()) countRT++;
}
```